# Question with Einstein Convention

Tags: conventions, notation

Quick question, lets say I have the following term

\begin{equation}
a_{\mu}b^{\mu}c_{\nu}d^{\nu}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

I have repeated indices over $a$ and $b$ so their components are summed over, and  I have repeated indices over $c$ and $d$ so their components are summed over. However, since the indices are repeated, I may relabel them:

\begin{equation}
a_{\mu}b^{\mu}c_{\mu}d^{\mu} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

This suggests that I can now sum the components of $b$ and $c$ and likewise with $a$ and $d$, etc. however I don't think this is valid and I just wanted to confirm. More specifically, as a general rule you should keep repeated indices unique to other repeated indices so confusions such as this don't occur. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Think about this analogy: in the double integral $\iint xy\ dx\ dy$, $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables, so you may relabel them. Does this mean you can change $y$ to $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  your conclusion is correct. The initial expression evaluates to just $(a \cdot b) (c \cdot d)$ while the rewriting of it to $a_{\mu}b^{\mu} c_{\mu} d^{\mu} $ is then meaningless (In Einstein summation convention you have an upper and lower repeated index and indices to be summed over come in pairs).

Comment: Hi thank you very much! I just edited my question slightly so take note to edit your answer accordingly. (I changed the final four vector c to d to make the statement more general)